# can't output char in Struct

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Flight {
    char flightNumber[6];
    int depHour;
    int depMin;
};

int main() {
    char flightNumber[6];
    int depHour;
    int depMin;
    cin.getline(flightNumber, 6);
    cin >> depHour;
    cin >> depMin;
    Flight f = {.flightNumber = flightNumber[6], .depHour=depHour , .depMin= depMin};
    cout << f.flightNumber << " " << f.depHour << " " << f.depMin << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Whatever I put in flightNumber doesn't show up. Compiles with no error but can't output flightNumber. It is empty. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: If you want to copy a null terminated string stored in a char array use `strcpy` or something similar, not the assignment operator.

Comment: Well, try `strlcpy` or `strncpy`, do not use `strcpy`, since it does not add '\0' automatically.http://www.gratisoft.us/todd/papers/strlcpy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.flightNumber = flightNumber[6]
```

That copies the character at index 6. Which is out of bounds on the array. And is therefore undefined behavior. This same bug also can cause you to print a string that is not null terminated, which also causes undefined behavior.

You need to use some form of `strncpy()`

That being said... I'm surprised this compiles with no warnings (and it does for me on clang).

#### Correct code version 1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Flight {
    char flightNumber[6];
    int depHour;
    int depMin;
};

int main() {
    char flightNumber[6];
    int depHour;
    int depMin;
    cin.getline(flightNumber, 6);
    cin >> depHour;
    cin >> depMin;
    Flight f = {.depHour=depHour , .depMin= depMin};
    strcpy(f.flightNumber, flightNumber);
    cout << f.flightNumber << " " << f.depHour << " " << f.depMin << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Correct code version 2:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Flight {
    Flight(char *flightNumber_, int depHour_, int depMin_): depHour(depHour_), depMin(depMin_) {
        strcpy(flightNumber, flightNumber_);
    }

    char flightNumber[6];
    int depHour;
    int depMin;
};

int main() {
    char flightNumber[6];
    int depHour;
    int depMin;
    cin.getline(flightNumber, 6);
    cin >> depHour;
    cin >> depMin;
    Flight f(flightNumber, depHour, depMin); 
    cout << f.flightNumber << " " << f.depHour << " " << f.depMin << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Notes:

- Don't use `strcpy()` like I did. Use `strncpy()` along with validation code to make sure you don't copy beyond the length of the allocated array.
- `std::string` is a lovely type in c++.

Comment: Flight f = {strcpy(.flightNumber,flightNumber), .depHour=depHour , .depMin= depMin};

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. It really helpful. Sr I can't thump up for your answer I just a new member. Anyway I refer the first solution. I a bit shorter than other and without constructor. Thank a bunch